# Tehilim and blessing others

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Maybe I need to read the psalms over again.
But the most psalms I can remember Talks about protection,blessing your animals,and so one.

But blessing your friends,  is there a psalm for blessing your friends?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of anything generic. Often, verses from Psalms are used to bless others for specific occasions.

One frequent example that I have heard is to bless people who are about to depart on a long journey using [Psalm 121:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43521&st=&pgnum=96). A rough English translation of that verse is

"G-d should guard your exiting and entering from now and forever."

My rabbi (and I have seen this as a common practice in many synagogues, esp. Conservative ones) blesses the congregation at the end of prayers with [Psalms 29:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43521&st=&pgnum=21):

"G-d shall grant strength to his nation. G-d shall bless his nation with peace."

Comment: But then you pray over them,I guess,when they are in the room?

Comment: @Aigle The best way to offer a blessing is personally. However, at least regarding the "Bon Voyage" blessing, I have seen people wish this via phone, text, emails, etc. I am adding another item or two to the above answer.